# Configuration issues with superset in K8s with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, apache-superset

I am trying to install superset using k8s with PostgreSQL as backend database and redis as cache layer.

Superset is up and running but when i try to run SQL queries, I am getting the following error

**column dbs.server_cert does not exist at character 814**

Below are my config files and helm templates. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
# Source: superset/templates/secret.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: superset
  labels:
    app: superset
    chart: superset-1.1.11
    release: superset
    heritage: Helm
    namespace: test
type: Opaque
data:
  superset_config.py: "attached seperately"
---

# Source: superset/templates/svc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: superset
  labels:
    app: superset
    chart: superset-1.1.11
    release: superset
    heritage: Helm
    namespace: test
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 8088
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: superset
    release: superset
---
# Source: superset/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: superset 
  labels:
    app: superset
    chart: superset-1.1.11
    release: superset
    heritage: Helm
    namespace: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: superset
      release: superset
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      name: superset
      labels:
        app: superset
        chart: superset-1.1.11
        release: superset
        heritage: Helm
      annotations:
        checksum/secrets: 6dd9c87c415d8a5a00981f36d8dca6ad69a2fdeae29d0caa3a02633be4acff07
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
      volumes:
        - name: superset-configs
          secret:
            secretName: superset
        - name: storage-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: superset-storage
      containers:
        - env:
          - name: PYTHONPATH
            value: "${PYTHONPATH}:/home/superset/superset/"
          image: amancevice/superset:0.36.0
          name: superset
          volumeMounts:
          - name: superset-configs
            mountPath: /home/superset/superset
          - name: storage-volume
            mountPath: /var/lib/superset
          ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 8088
            protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 2
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: http
            initialDelaySeconds: 80
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 2
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: http
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
---

 #PVC

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: superset-storage
  namespace: test
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

**superset config file**

```
import os

def get_env_variable(var_name, default=None):
    """Get the environment variable or raise exception.

    Args:
        var_name (str): the name of the environment variable to look up
        default (str): the default value if no env is found
    """
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        if default is not None:
            return default
        raise RuntimeError(
            'The environment variable {} was missing, abort...'
            .format(var_name)
        )

# Postgres

POSTGRES_USER =  '**'
POSTGRES_PASSWORD = '**'
POSTGRES_HOST = '**'
POSTGRES_PORT = '**'
POSTGRES_DB = '**'

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}'.format(
    POSTGRES_USER,
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    POSTGRES_HOST,
    POSTGRES_PORT,
    POSTGRES_DB,
)


# Redis

REDIS_HOST = '**' 
REDIS_PORT = '**'


# Celery

class CeleryConfig:
    BROKER_URL = 'redis://{0}:{1}/0'.format(REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT)
    CELERY_IMPORTS = ('superset.sql_lab',)
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://{0}:{1}/1'.format(REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT)
    CELERY_ANNOTATIONS = {'tasks.add': {'rate_limit': '10/s'}}
    CELERY_TASK_PROTOCOL = 1


CELERY_CONFIG = CeleryConfig

FLASK_APP=superset
```

**ERROR**

```
 sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column dbs.server_cert does not exist
LINE 1: ...rm, dbs.impersonate_user AS dbs_impersonate_user, dbs.server...
                                                             ^

[SQL: SELECT dbs.created_on AS dbs_created_on, dbs.changed_on AS dbs_changed_on, dbs.id AS dbs_id, dbs.verbose_name AS dbs_verbose_name, dbs.database_name AS dbs_database_name, dbs.sqlalchemy_uri AS dbs_sqlalchemy_uri, dbs.password AS dbs_password, dbs.cache_timeout AS dbs_cache_timeout, dbs.select_as_create_table_as AS dbs_select_as_create_table_as, dbs.expose_in_sqllab AS dbs_expose_in_sqllab, dbs.allow_run_async AS dbs_allow_run_async, dbs.allow_csv_upload AS dbs_allow_csv_upload, dbs.allow_ctas AS dbs_allow_ctas, dbs.allow_dml AS dbs_allow_dml, dbs.force_ctas_schema AS dbs_force_ctas_schema, dbs.allow_multi_schema_metadata_fetch AS dbs_allow_multi_schema_metadata_fetch, dbs.extra AS dbs_extra, dbs.encrypted_extra AS dbs_encrypted_extra, dbs.perm AS dbs_perm, dbs.impersonate_user AS dbs_impersonate_user, dbs.server_cert AS dbs_server_cert, dbs.created_by_fk AS dbs_created_by_fk, dbs.changed_by_fk AS dbs_changed_by_fk 
FROM dbs ORDER BY dbs.changed_on DESC 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s]
```

After applying this configuration, I did an exec into the pod and ran the following commands:

1. superset db upgrade
2. superset init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the migrations have not completed successfully. Try executing the following inside the superset container

```
superset db upgrade
```

in order to perform the migrations.

Although, you shouldn't have to manually execute commands in the container to get it working. The superset [helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/superset/) accepts an `initFile` as a value to achieve this without having to manually exec into the container.